# Non blocking spring controller giving 503 error when 500 request sent at once

Tags: spring-boot

I have been trying to do load testing(500 request in 1 second) with gatling for following three request handlers created with spring boot. Inspired by http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/04/22/c10k-developing-non-blocking-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/
but i received reverse output. "getUser" -BLOCKING request handler was able to handle 500 request in 1 second(but launched more then 200 threads).
"getUser2" and "getUser3" which are NONBLOCKING resulted in 503 error after handling around 10 request out of 500 request.
screen shot of gatling output: https://ibb.co/ePEEBk
Can somebody please explain me the reason or what I am doing wrong.

```
@RequestMapping("/getUser2")
public CompletionStage<Object> getUser2() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
        try {
            logger.info("");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "result";
    });
}

@RequestMapping("getUser3")
public DeferredResult<String> getUser3() {
    DeferredResult<String> def = new DeferredResult<String>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> {
        logger.info("");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).whenCompleteAsync((res,err)-> {
        def.setResult("result");
    });
    return def;
}

@RequestMapping("getUser")
public String getUser() {
    try {
        logger.info("");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "result";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have got the answer.
But for getUser3(), it seems your REST api is timed out. By default it will use the default timeout from the Spring MVC.
One thing you can do is to create a DeferredResult with a timeout value.

```
DeferredResult(java.lang.Long timeout)
```

See this constructor for further information https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html#DeferredResult-java.lang.Long-

For getUser, it should be the same, you probably need a longer timeout to fix it